How to solve SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY FAILED while inserting to SUPABASE table
I've been trying to insert to a table in Supabase but face: httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from supabase import create_client, Client
import requests

load_dotenv()

os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE']='ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt'
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = 'ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt'
SUPABASE_URL = os.environ['SUPABASE_URL']
SUPABASE_KEY = os.environ['SUPABASE_KEY']


supabase: Client = create_client(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY)

I have been setting the environment variables to avoid the SSL errors but it doesn't work this time. I am getting error while trying to insert data into the table:
response = supabase.table('chat_history_projectsearch').insert(data).execute()

